# How can I combine the commands leave and say?

Tags: linux, bash, macos

Is there a way to make use of the command `leave` and the command `say` (MacOS) to be notified by the built in voice system?

I can do `echo hello | say` on the command line.

`leave` outputs `Time to leave!` how can this output be piped to `say` once it appears?

When I issue this command it's just hanging. (no leave process is created)

```
# one minute from now
leave +0001
Alarm set for Fri Jun  3 15:55:05 CEST 2022. (pid 37692)
pgrep leave
37692
# triggers: Time to leave!

# one minute from now piped to say
# this one is just hanging there.... (no leave process created)
leave +0001 | say
```

**man leave**

```
LEAVE(1)                  BSD General Commands Manual                 LEAVE(1)

NAME
     leave -- remind you when you have to leave

SYNOPSIS
     leave [[+]hhmm]

DESCRIPTION
     The leave utility waits until the specified time, then reminds you that you have to leave.  You are reminded 5 minutes and 1 minute before the actual time, at
     the time, and every minute thereafter.  When you log off, leave exits just before it would have printed the next message.

     The following options are available:

     hhmm    The time of day is in the form hhmm where hh is a time in hours (on a 12 or 24 hour clock), and mm are minutes.  All times are converted to a 12 hour
             clock, and assumed to be in the next 12 hours.

     +       If the time is preceded by `+', the alarm will go off in hours and minutes from the current time.

     If no argument is given, leave prompts with "When do you have to leave?".  A reply of newline causes leave to exit, otherwise the reply is assumed to be a
     time.  This form is suitable for inclusion in a .login or .profile.

     To get rid of leave you should either log off or use `kill -s KILL' giving its process id.

SEE ALSO
     calendar(1)

HISTORY
     The leave command appeared in 3.0BSD.

BSD                             April 28, 1995                             BSD
```

Thank you!

Comment: We need more information. Does `leave` terminate immediately after emitting that output? Does it keep running indefinitely?

Comment: Do you want each line of output from `leave` to go into a separate copy of `say`, or is that moot because there's only one line of output in the first place, written just before exit?

Comment: Also, what did you try, and how did it fail? If you didn't even try `leave | say`, you should really do that before asking so you can include details about how exactly its behavior differed from your expectations, if in fact it differed at all.

Comment: Or is this sent direct to a tty (or something like `wall`) instead of stdout? (If that's the case, how much do you care about using the original `leave` command vs something that does the same thing without actively trying to prevent its output from being piped)?

Comment: Good point @CharlesDuffy. It's hanging: leave 1546 | say

Comment: That sounds like the "each line of output from `leave` to go into a separate copy of `say`" behavior is what you need.

Comment: Maybe you can use `coproc` or something like that to capture the `write` to `STDOUT_FILENO` triggered by `leave`

Comment: @0stone0, ...that's somewhat overkill, isn't it?

Comment: Apparently it is, but thet `leave` would still be able to run in the background. Your pipe solutions makes `leave` 'hang' in foreground until it's done. Seems unhandy to have a terminal open until leave triggers.

Comment: @0stone0, nothing about the pipe intrinsically needs to be in the foreground any more than code reading from a coproc needs to be in the foreground.

Comment: @0stone0, that is to say, `( leave | { IFS= read -r line; say <<<"$line"; } ) </dev/null &` is just as in-the-background as fancy coproc code is.

Comment: Ah yea, overcomplicating things, thanks again for the info. I'd add the last command to your answer, think that that command is perfect for OP. Tested here and works fine, each sentence is played trough say.

Comment: @0stone0, amended per suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `leave` writes one line of output per day. If `say` is trying to read all of stdin at a go (or otherwise do any kind of a read that is *not* one-character-at-a-time stopping at the first newline), the buffer will never be full enough for its read to complete in a reasonable time period.

The bash `read` builtin does these (inefficient) one-character-at-a-time reads, and so is able to get content from a pipeline more appropriately (as long as `leave` is overriding libc's default buffering behavior, which switches from line-buffered to fully-buffered when output is not direct to a TTY; but if it doesn't do this, that's a bug you should report to your OS vendor).

---

To run a new copy of `say` for each line of output from `leave`:

```
leave | while IFS= read -r line; do say <<<"$line"; done
```

To wait until `leave` has some output, run `say` exactly once, then exit:

```
leave | { IFS= read -r line; say <<<"$line"; }
```

---

All of this can be put in the background if you choose. For example:

```
{ leave | { IFS= read -r line; say <<<"$line"; }
} </dev/null >leave-say.log 2>&1 & disown -h "$!"
```

...will do an equivalent of running the above code in the background with `nohup`, writing any errors to `leave-say.log` instead of `nohup.out`.

Comment: `leave` does a `write(STDOUT_FILENO, MSG4, sizeof(MSG4)` for the messages. You do not need to run a separate copy of `say` for each line.

Comment: @LjmDullaart, depends on how `say` is handling its stdin. It's good that it's being adequately flushed on the write side, but that doesn't tell me what size chunks it's being read in on the consuming side. The OP _did_ specify in the question (err, in a comment on the question) that `leave | say` on its own doesn't work as-expected; whereas bash's `read` builtin invokes a bunch of 1-byte reads so it'll never be waiting for content beyond the first record delimiter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : `say` does  `while(!feof(stdin)) 
   {
    p_text[ix++] = fgetc(stdin);`  Furthermore, all output of `leave` are full lines.

Comment: @LjmDullaart, if it's reading until EOF before it takes any action, there's the problem. That implies that, if we want it to take action when there's only one line of input, we *should* have it act on individual lines.

Comment: @LjmDullaart, ...as for "all output of leave are full lines", what relevance does that have? Line buffering is an output-side thing, not an input-side thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The version of `say` that I have reads till an end-of line or EOF before taking action. Because the end-of-line triggers the speaking, it is relevant that `leave` produces fill lines.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: the OP stated it in his comment why it was not working ". It's hanging: leave 1546 | say ".  That was the symptom. Of course it hangs until the child dies, unless you background it.

Comment: @LjmDullaart, sure, but if it was hanging _and also actually `say`ing the text_, that would be a very different problem. @BjarteBrandt, could you step in to clarify here? (If the "problem" was just that the program stayed in the foreground _but it actually worked_, that really should have been specified in the question).

Answer (score 0):

What `leave` does is fork a background process that gives the leaving messages on STDOUT. When the fork is done, the child process inherits the STDOUT from its parent. When the parent dies, the child keeps the STDIN of the next process in the pipe open. Therefore,

```
leave +0002  | sed 's/o/OOOO/g'
```

seems to hang until the child process is killed.

The correct solution would be to background the rest of the pipe:

```
leave  +0002  | sed 's/o/OOOO/g' &
```

which produces then:

```
Just OOOOne mOOOOre minute!
Time tOOOO leave!
```

Or, in your case:

```
leave  +0002  |say &
```

Killing the child process will stop `say` form 'hanging'. The PID of the child is given in the message `Alarm set for xx.xx. (pid 3311636)`. You can verify this by killing the child from a different window.

Not that, if you do not leave, the child process will not die, but will keep on nagging from time to time. This means that `say` will"

- say "alarm set for  pid  (output from the parent)
- hang for a while waiting for input
- say "Just one more minute!" (output from the child)
- hang for another minute
- say "Time to leave" (output from the child)
- hang for another minute
- say "Time to leave" (output from the child)

(last two lines repeated until the  child is killed)

This is consistent also with the Macos manpage for `say` that states:

> If the input is a TTY, or if no text is specified, the typed input text will be spoken line by line